# android - proguard error in android studio

Tags: android, proguard

I want to use proguard for my application ,I enabled it but when I want to generate apk file ,it gives me this error:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJpWasabeefRecyclerviewAnimators122Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:proguardRelease
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory extends or implements program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
Warning:org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:there were 17 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I'm using the latest version of sdk 23 , this is my gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

What is wrong ? where I do wrong in this code?

thanks

Comment: I'm wondering about your dependency `    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')`  ... if you're using the legacy apache lib, you don't need the jar, you just need to add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`to your `android {}` section.

Answer (score 21):

Just add this on proguard:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
```

Comment: can you please explain how this work as i have started using proguard from today

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned in your logcat check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass

You have duplicate class definitions in your application dependencies and this is just warnings.

Now If you want to fix it then please add below code in your proguard-android.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn  org.apache.**
-dontwarn  jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.**
-dontwarn  com.nostra13.universalimageloader.**
-dontwarn  org.acra.** 

#wasabeef recyclerview
-keep class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#HTTP Legacy
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Universal Image Loader
-keep class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Acra
-keep class org.acra.**  { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Support libraries
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature





# Keep the annotations
-keepattributes *Annotation*


-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''


-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

**Note** : proguard-android.txt location -> android-sdk-path\tools\proguard

Thanks.!!

Comment: Wow, that's a giant proguard file..  which do you think are the important bits related to the question?