# ProGuard: duplicate definition of library class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I run my ProGuard for my Android project and get the following warnings:

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]

Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535346/android-proguard-error-in-android-studio) to fix this with ignoring it with:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
```

I do not see a way to remove the duplicates from the used libraries. Even after using `dontwarn` the warnings do not vanish.

**Is this the right way of handling this warning in just ignoring it or could this lead to problems?**

Comment: it seems you imported some classes from multiple library. you might add android library jar inside of proguard config

Comment: Could you please post an example for that. Android plrguard def says that you should not use: libraryjars. See: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass

Comment: post your `progaurd` rule file

Comment: @confile did you solve your issue?

Comment: I solved this by dropping the apache library from my project and replacing with my own code.

Answer (score 98):

If you add a proguard option `-printconfiguration config.txt` you'll see proguard adds

> -libraryjars 'D:\tools\android\platforms\android-23\android.jar'
>
> -libraryjars 'D:\tools\android\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar'

your duplicated classes (e.g. SslError) are presented in both android.jar and org.apache.http.legacy.jar

Proguard adds second jar even if you don't `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`
Here is an [open bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194513) describing the problem.

So now we can't do anything with the issue. Just ignore it:

```
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
```

There is no need to keep the classes as long as they are located in library jar (phone's library actually).
dontwarn doesn't work because it's not a warning, it's a note.

Comment: Great! Thanks. This answers should be marked as the correct one!

Comment: Just tried to place `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in *build.gradle* and place your `-dontnote` into the proguard file. But still getting problems. I was using api 22, was working fine. Now I upgrade into 23, I'm getting these errors when trying to build the signed. Some times grade works for indefinite. Don't know what else to do.

Comment: Where I add this option `proguard option -printconfiguration config.txt` ?

Comment: In command line were you run proguard. The config.txt will be created at the current folder

Answer (score 6):

Probably, you have mentioned "-injars" and -libraryjars" in your proguard-project.txt,considering the latest build system takes care of mentioning them for you ..so you dont need to mention it again.

source: 
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass

I think this will help.:)

Comment: Well, I'm on a pretty new Android Studio (Dec 1, 2015 build) and nobody takes care of mentioning them for me. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell gradle not to allow duplicate classes (take only the first) by adding the following to your build.gradle:

```
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Comment: Which build.gradle? project or app? if app, under which block do you place it? i have tried to put it in my app's build.gradle android block `android{jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

}` but i get the error **Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'jar()'**

Comment: `jar {` is a task within the gradle java plugin, so if you `apply plugin: 'java'` then you should be able to use that jar block; it doesn't go inside another block; it's at the root level of the build.gradle. ([see this gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:jar)) I used it in an app, but not sure if that matters.

Answer (score -9):

You can try this in your build.gradle for everything that is indicated as duplicate in the logs. I am not sure if this will work, so try it out and inform if it works or not.

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'android.net.http.SslCertificate'
    }
```