# Building APK on :mobile:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard

dear community,
I am trying to build an APK file of my Android app, but the Gradle Build has stuck on :mobile:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease for 3 hours. 
Here is my **build.graddle** for the project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mrgkanev.remote"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
// Flavor

    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/plus/java'] } }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile project(':materialDesign')
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.7.3'
    compile project(':FloatingMenu')
    compile('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

}
```

and here is the **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
```

My **proguard-rules.pro** file contains this code, because I previously had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047806/proguard-duplicate-definition-of-library-class)

I am convinced that there is no point of waiting anymore and something should be done. What will you advice me?

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

This brings in *all* of Google Play Services. It is very unlikely that you are using even most of Google Play Services, let alone all of it. Plus, that version is *years* out of date.

Follow [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), specifically the "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" section, and only include the pieces of Play Services that you really need.