# Unable to build release apk

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

I am trying to build my project to get the release apk I'm getting bunch of warnings where I'm not able to get it working

Warning:

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpServerConnection]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParamBean]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.DefaultedHttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParamBean]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpConnectionMetrics]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderIterator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderElement]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderElementIterator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.LineParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.HeaderGroup]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BufferedHeader]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicTokenIterator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicListHeaderIterator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.HeaderValueFormatter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.LineFormatter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicRequestLine]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.HeaderValueParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.ParserCursor]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpVersion]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecParamBean]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookiePathComparator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.ClientCookie]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.SetCookie]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.SM]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecRegistry]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieAttributeHandler]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.SetCookie2]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.CookieIdentityComparator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.TokenIterator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.ProtocolException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.ReasonPhraseCatalog]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.io.HttpMessageWriter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.io.HttpTransportMetrics]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.io.HttpMessageParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.io.SessionOutputBuffer]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.NameValuePair]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParamBean]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.NTUserPrincipal]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.Credentials]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.InvalidCredentialsException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthState]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.BasicUserPrincipal]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AUTH]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeRegistry]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpHost]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpStatus]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.HttpRequest]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogSource]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.Log]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringDecoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryDecoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BinaryCodec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.EncoderException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryEncoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.RefinedSoundex]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.Metaphone]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.Soundex]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone$DoubleMetaphoneResult]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoderComparator]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.Encoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.RFC1522Codec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.BCodec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.QCodec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.HttpResponseCache]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]

Note: there were 408 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'

Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
Warning: library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

Note: com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.aa: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.youtube.api.locallylinked.LocallyLinkedFactory
Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager
Note: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy
Note: com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Note: com.google.protobuf.zzc: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry
Note: com.google.protobuf.zzd: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.protobuf.Extension
Note: com.google.protobuf.zze: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.io.Memory
Note: com.google.protobuf.zze: can't find dynamically referenced class org.robolectric.Robolectric
Note: com.squareup.picasso.Utils: can't find dynamically referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$CloseGuard: can't find dynamically referenced class dalvik.system.CloseGuard
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: org.apache.commons.logging.LogSource: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
Note: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority
Note: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
Note: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level

Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program 

Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setDefaultAudience(com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginBehavior(com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipStyle(com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipMode(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setProperties(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginManager(com.facebook.login.LoginManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView { void setCaretPosition(com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.DeviceShareButton { void setShareContent(com.facebook.share.model.ShareContent); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.model.ShareContent'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setLikeViewStyle(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setAuxiliaryViewPosition(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setHorizontalAlignment(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButtonBase { void setShareContent(com.facebook.share.model.ShareContent); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.model.ShareContent'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView { YouTubePlayerView(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int,com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$b); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$b'
Note: there were 4 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 16 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 17 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)

Warning: there were 126 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 33 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFreeRelease FAILED
```

This is how it is in release build type:

```
 release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Now I have added some rules in proguard.txt as well as proguard.pro but sometimes its taking long time to build and its not happening.

Where do I need to add the rules correctly and what are the rules I need to add ?

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.myinnos:AwesomeImagePicker:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'

    // Dependencies for the REST API example
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'

    //Dependency for Facebook Sign-In
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

}
```

Comment: Please provide your library dependencies

Comment: @GeniusQ- Updated with the dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047806/proguard-duplicate-definition-of-library-class

Comment: @NovoLucas- That didn't work still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution posting here if someone like me who is struggling to get it worked.

Add this to your proguard.pro file

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Its worked for me and issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can tell gradle not to allow duplicate classes (take only the first) by adding the following to your build.gradle:

```
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Comment: where do I need to add this in build.gradle?

Comment: Where to place it, I am getting "Could not find method jar() for arguments [build_54rwgi5hsmpxoalhjxi32c2u3$_run_closure1$_closure8@7952e383]"when I try to place it in android {}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem get solved after adding this to build file:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

And to proguard config:

```
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
*;
}
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
*;
}
```