# proguard Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.PostConstruct]

Tags: java, spring-boot, proguard

I try start ProGuard on Spring Boot App And get error:

```
  [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Generated]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.PostConstruct]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.PreDestroy]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resource$AuthenticationType]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resource]
     [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resources]
     [proguard] Note: there were 8 duplicate class definitions.
     [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
     [proguard] Warning: there were 2 classes in incorrectly named files.
     [proguard]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
     [proguard]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
     [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
     [proguard]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
     [proguard]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
     [proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following to get rid of the situation:

1. If you add a proguard option `-printconfiguration configuration.txt` you will see all the proguard adds.
2. Based on what you receive from the step above, you could correct the same

**OR**

You could use the following option to stop seeing these warning messages: Documentation [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#dontnote)

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.*
-dontnote javax.annotation.*
```

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047806/proguard-duplicate-definition-of-library-class) question for more details on the situation that you're facing right now.

Answer (score 0):

try ignore class `-dontnote javax.annotation.*`

and read more:
https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass